# Weird JSON parsing issues with Ruby

Tags: ruby, json, parsing

I'm downloading content from a webpage that seems to be in JSON.  It is a large file with the following format:

```
"address1":"123 Street","address2":"Apt 1","city":"City","state":"ST","zip":"xxxxx","country":"US"
```

There are about 1000 of these entries, where each entry is contained within brackets.  When I download the page using RestClient.get (open-uri for some reason was throwing a http 500 error), the data is in the following format:

```
\"address\1":\"123 Street\",\"address2\":\"Apt 1\",\"city\":\"City\",\"state\":\"ST\",\"zip\":\"xxxxx\",\"country\":\"US\"
```

When I then use the json class

```
parsed = JSON.parse(data_out)
```

it completely scrambles both the order of entries within the data structure, and also the order of the objects within each entry, for example:

```
"address1"=>"123 Street", "city"=>"City", "country"=>"US", "address2"=>"Apt 1"
```

If instead I use

```
data_j=data_out.to_json
```

then I get:

```
\\\"address\\\1":\\\"123 Street\\\",\\\"address2\\\":\\\"Apt 1\\\",\\\"city\\\":\\\"City\\\",\\\"state\\\":\\\"ST\\\",\\\"zip\\\":\\\"xxxxx\\\",\\\"country\\\":\\\"US\\\"
```

Further, only using the json class seems to allow me to select the entries I want:

```
parsed[1]["address1"]
=> "123 Street"

data_j[1]["address1"]
TypeError: can't convert String into Integer
from (irb):17:in `[]'
from (irb):17
from :0
```

Any idea whats going on?  I guess since the json commands are working I can use them, but it is disconcerting that its scrambling the entries and order of the objects.

Comment: Object are unordered. There is no "scrambling" because there is no defined ordering.

Comment: The to_json method just dumps the content to a json string, which is why you can't index it the way you're trying to. You're basically just converting your json string into a json string using that method.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for explaining the difference between the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the data appears ordered in string form, it *represents* an unordered dataset. The line:

```
parsed = JSON.parse(data_out)
```

which you use is the correct way to convert the string form into something usable in Ruby. I cannot see the full structure from your example, so I don't know whether the top level is an array or id-based hash. I suspect the latter since you say it becomes unordered when you view from Ruby. Therefore, if you knew which part of the address you were interested in you might have code like this:

```
# Writes all the cities
parsed.each do |id,data|
   puts data["city"]
end
```

If the outer structure is an array, you'd do this:

```
# Writes all the cities
parsed.each do |data|
   puts data["city"]
end
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I ended up doing!